# Hide overflowing table cell content in IE7 with CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have an anchor element inside a table cell. The anchor needs to overlap subsequent cells, but not be visible outside of the table or containing div.

HTML

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Volkswagen Crafter CR30 SWB Diesel 2.5 BlueTDI 88PS Van</span> BF60GKK <br>updated 06 dec 17:49</th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td><a style="width: 237.5%;left:37.5%" href="#"><span>John Smith, Provisional<br/>09:00 on 12 Dec<br/>18:00 on 14 Dec</span></a></td>
        <td>g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
div {overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;position:relative}
th,td {border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; position:relative; width:50px; }
th {width:150px;}
td.d {background-color:#cdc;}
a {z-index:1000;position:absolute;width:300px;top:15px;left:5px;height:60px;overflow:hidden;background:#fdd;}
```

This works in Chrome, IE8 and IE9…

[image: Correct rendering in Chrome]

But not in IE7…

[image: Incorrect rendering in IE7]

How can I make this work in IE7?

See working example here http://jsfiddle.net/UrZDw/

Also, IE7 also puts the anchor behind cells which have a background colour. How can I fix this?

Comment: try this http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: Thanks @raym0nd - doesn't seem to fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
table { overflow: hidden; }
```

Then your `td`s will inherit that, so you'll need to explicitly set:

```
table td { overflow: visible; }
```

Comment: Thanks @wanovak, but unfortunately that did not work. I have tried it here http://jsfiddle.net/UrZDw/1/